# Exclude a chunk enclused in a string in regular expression

Tags: regex

I have a text similar to:

> In which **marked** text should match before, but `<tag>`*marked*
>   should not match inside a tag`</tag>`. Also **marked** should matched
>   after the tag. `<tag>`This *marked* should not match either`</tag>`

For this example of text, bold instances of marked should get matched, but not the one which is inside `<tag>`. 
The nearest I was able to go was https://regex101.com/r/CyxVZ3/1 which ignores all matches before `</tag>`.

Few updates from comments:

- `<tag>..</tag>` may occur several times
- Nesting of `<tag>` would not
  be there.
- Preferable language is JAVA.

Comment: Can't you find the first and last match programmatically with code?

Comment: first and last was for this example only, I've updated the question.

Comment: Can `<tag>` `</tag>` occur several times ?

Comment: yes, it can occur multiple times

Comment: Can `<tag>` be nested? Eg: `<tag>Some text <tag>no match</tag>
 <tag>marked</tag></tag>`.

If it can, you should use an XML parser, not a regex

Comment: Which regex engine are you using (which language)? This is important because of different features/syntax between engines.

Comment: I am using Java 7

Comment: @Eily, no, the idea for this is to avoid nesting, so that already marked text does not get marked again.

Comment: The nesting issue is about the nature of the input: if it has no nested tag blocks, a regex is possible. No regex can deal with finding and ignoring nested tag blocks; that takes recursive parsing.

Answer (score 1):

if engines supports backtracking control verbs (Perl,PHP) :

```
<tag>.*?<\/tag>(*SKIP)(?!)|(?:(?!<tag>).)*
```

otherwise it's not possible with one regex it will need some more code.

After reading comments in java 7 it can be done using scanner and using regex as delimiter, for example:

```
String string = "In which marked text should match before, but <tag>marked should not match inside a tag</tag>. Also marked should matched after the tag.<tag>This marked should not match either</tag> done";
try ( Scanner scanner = new Scanner( string ) ) {
    scanner.useDelimiter( "<tag>.*?</tag>" );
    while ( scanner.hasNext() ) {
        System.out.println( scanner.next() );
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly needed the first part(which is not supported in java :( ), for the java part, we would have to reconstruct the string again..